# HTML5 video & Chrome/Webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, html5-video

I've got some trouble with the `<video>` element I guess. I have a little demo page where I'm running a video. That file is available in `.webm`, `.mp4` and `.ogv`. The video is played properly in *Firefox (10) mac+win*, *Safari mac*, *Chrome mac*.

Neither the *windows* version of Safari nor Chrome plays/shows that video file (maybe a Webkit issue?). This is how the HTML code looks:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="video/chicane.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="video/chicane.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="video/chicane.ogv" type="video/ogv"/>
</video>
```

I'm also using a `.htaccess` file to normalize MIME types, looks like

```
# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v
AddType video/webm                     webm
```

Having a look into Chromes or Safaris developer tools (network tab), it looks like it chooses to play the `.webm` file, but it can't figure the `mime type` (shows undefined), plus it seems like it trys to access the files twice.

Have a look yourself:

[**http://www.typeofnan.com**](http://www.typeofnan.com) **("awesome tab")**

I have no clue why it works fine on OSX with both browsers, if someone can spot an error on the site please let me know. At present, I do some feature detection and [use Javascript to `.play()`](https://github.com/jAndreas/typeof-NaN-2.0/blob/master/js/modules/o_box3d.js#L189) the video. However, if I use the `autoplay` attribute on the `<video>` tag, Chrome at least plays the audio, but still no video at all.

Reference: [Site source on github](https://github.com/jAndreas/typeof-NaN-2.0)

Comment: The video should show by clicking on the "awsomeness" tab ?

Comment: @Zakaria: exactly. Thanks for the heads up, I've updated the question.

Comment: (FWIW, Chrome 17) Its not issuing the request twice, I'm not sure what the 1st entry in chromes dev tools is as its not shown with any request paramaters, but looking at the request in Fiddler (debugging proxy) its issued only once and responds correctly with a size+video/webm, it plays after downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add `codecs` additional info into each `<source>` ?
Maybe WebKit cannot automatically recognize codec used to encode the video source.

```
// from html5rocks.com, see link on the bottom of answer
<video>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-markup

Comment: yes - I had the codecs specified. But it doesn't help + it does not even seem to be necesarry at all. I just added the codec for the `webm` file btw.

Comment: @jAndy looks like, my second tip is to try providing only single video source, and work out which format is supported. When you go to the provided link and try to play sample videos, does it work for you?

Comment: yes thats the confusing part for me. Also the demos on `html5rocks` work properly for me in chrome/win.

Comment: @jAndy so that means, your browser/OS combination is working properly, and the problem exists in your code. Are you sure of what codecs you used for encoding video?

Comment: I added all the codecs/syntax exactly like on the demo page you provided. Did not help for me on `win/chrome 16`

Comment: @jAndy my last tip is to put your video on standalone page, without that nice cube and all JS/GL, and test if you can play it. If not, I have nothing else than suspicion that your a/v files are not encoded as you think they are. sorry if neither this cannot help you

Comment: @jAndy Hi, so can you please point out what was the real solution? I'd like to (or you can too) edit the answer to fit the real reason of problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did to get it to work.  Since the browser accepts the first video it can play, I put the WEBM version first and Chrome has no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine : Windows 7 Family + Chrome 16.
What I did is that I opened the Developer Tools.
Then, I added the  `autoplay="autoplay"` to the `video` tag. Next, I edited the html `source` tag related to the `webm` format so that I could have :

```
<source src="video/chicane.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=\" vp8, vorbis\"">
```

Maybe it was simply an escape problem (with the double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this markup from scratch using your video URLs, and it seems to work fine:

```
<video controls width="360" height="360">
    <source src="http://www.typeofnan.com/video/chicane.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.typeofnan.com/video/chicane.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://www.typeofnan.com/video/chicane.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">Your video</span>
</video>
<p>
    <strong>Download video:</strong> <a href="http://www.typeofnan.com/video/chicane.mp4">MP4 format</a> | <a href="http://www.typeofnan.com/video/chicane.ogv">Ogg format</a> | <a href="http://www.typeofnan.com/video/chicane.webm">WebM format</a>
</p>
```

See [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody).